# How to configure SLF4J in Apache MINA

Tags: logging, slf4j, apache-mina, ftp-server

We are using the Apache FTPServer library which in turn uses MINA in a project as 3rd party libraries. MINA is using SLF4J for logging.
I am wondering how I can redirect the logging output of MINA to our own standard log files, which are using java.util.logging. The JAR for the respective JDK binding (slf4j-jdk14-1.7.5.jar) is already on the class path, but I don’t see any logging from MINA in the log files. In a way, this doesn't surprise me, because how would MINA know about the existing log files.

Do I need to create a specific configuration somewhere? If yes, what, where and how? 
I have read through all the documentation of MINA, SLF4J and FTPServer, but couldn’t find anything. (Sorry, if I am missing something obvious).

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been resolved. It was not directly related to SLF4J or MINA, but rather to the fact that the modified MINA-Jar was located in the wrong directory of the application and, therefore, was not loaded.